# In T-SQL, how to insert a new row with all values set by default?

Tags: sql, t-sql, syntax, insert, default-value

In Microsoft SQL database, I have a table where every column have default values (either fixed values or stuff like identity or `getdate()`).

I am trying to write an SQL statement which will insert a new row in which every cell will have a default value.

Neither

```
insert into MySchema.MyTable
```

nor

```
insert into MySchema.MyTable () values ()
```

are valid syntax.

So is it possible to insert a new row without specifying any value?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`insert into foo DEFAULT VALUES`

Answer (score 0):

## Standard SQL

`INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ( DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT... )`

When the `DEFAULT` reserved keyword is used in place of an actual value, it means the default value of the field. This allows you to specify some columns but not others.

The syntax is part of the SQL standard, and works on most databases since 2005:

- [MS SQL TSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - [2005+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms174335(v%3Dsql.90))
- [Oracle PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9015.htm#i2122346) - [10g r2+](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2122346)
- [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) - [5.5+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)/[4.1+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-archive.html)
- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-insert.html) - [8.0+](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-insert.htm)
- [DB2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_insert.html), [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#insert), etc.

(Simple databases, such as SQLite or Access, tends to not support these "new" or "advanced" syntax.)

## Non-Standard

`INSERT INTO tablename DEFAULT VALUES`

This will insert a new row populating everything with default values.

As far as I know this syntax is non-standard, and few databases support it - I know only MS SQL and PostgreSQL.
While I personally don't use it, I can see the use case and it may be made standard like `DEFAULT` fields in the future.

Comment: This does not work in TSQL (i.e. Microsoft SQL Server). "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

Comment: @DaveBoltman Can't believe I made an answer that was so simple. I took some time to test to make sure the syntax works, and it is indeed standard, you just need to specify it for every field that you want default of. I've updated the answer and linked to syntax documentations.