# How do I insert a row in T-SQL where there are only auto-generated columns?

Tags: t-sql, insert

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TRACEABLE](
        [TRACEABLE_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL 
              CONSTRAINT [DF_TRACEABLE_TRACEABLE_ID]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TRACEABLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TRACEABLE_ID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

How do I insert a row into this table?  This doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO TRACEABLE() VALUES()
```

It errors on the `VALUES()` clause (Incorrect syntax near ')').  Taking out the brackets doesn't work either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In T-SQL, how to insert a new row with all values set by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078248/in-t-sql-how-to-insert-a-new-row-with-all-values-set-by-default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TRACEABLE DEFAULT VALUES;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO TRACEABLE VALUES (DEFAULT);
```